# Principal component (PC) as a substitute for colinear covariates?

Tags: regression, pca, spatial, multicollinearity

I am working on a spatial linear regression and I can tell there is collinearity between covariates. Can I use PCA (Principal Component Analysis) images instead of original covariates to estimate the dependent variable? I am assuming PC1=Variable 1, PC2=Variable 2, etc. Or are there any other methods to solve the collinearity problem?

Comment: What is your goal in fitting the regression model? Collinearity is only a problem in some cases.

Comment: I am trying to estimate the response variable from covariates using spatial linear regression.

Comment: To be more specific: are you interested in the magnitudes and directions of the coefficients, or making accurate predictions, or both?

Comment: **@ssdecontrol** .Both the coefficients and sign of the predictors as well as accurate estimation of response variable using these PC's of covariates.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that will help me write a more helpful answer.

Comment: How correlated?  Usually only a problem if the correlation is above .95.

Comment: Yes, why not? This is called principal components regression.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called partial least square that is something very close to what you are trying to do.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression

The choice to use the PCA transformation of the data can lead to a better estimation of the output $y$ but to understand the role of the original variables  will be more difficult.

I suggest you to start with  the lasso estimator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_%28statistics%29#Lasso_method